# Cake on OSX fails with "error: the assembly name is invalid"

Tags: .net, mono, cakebuild

I tried to use cake for the first time today and got the error above. I was initially using the cake package from homebrew, but to simplify the problem I downloaded the cake example project (https://github.com/cake-build/example), but all of the following commands give the same error output:

```
./build.sh
cake
mono tools/Cake/Cake.exe
```

I have tried using `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug MONO_LOG_MASK=dll` to output more detailed logging but nothing seems obviously relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is caused by a problem with mono 6.8.0. I eventually found this: https://www.gitmemory.com/KSP-CKAN which describes other users having a similar problem after upgrading. After I uninstalled cake and mono and reverted to mono 6.6.0 cake worked fine.