# Getting ##[error] Bash exited with code '1' in an azure-devops pipeline bash cake task with agent Ubuntu-16.04

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a pipeline that runs on a linux agent Ubuntu-16.04 with image version 20200119.1

https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1604-README.md

It runs a bash cake task and returns

```
Restoring NuGet package Cake.0.36.0.
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/cake/0.36.0/cake.0.36.0.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/cake/0.36.0/cake.0.36.0.nupkg 12ms
Installing Cake 0.36.0.
Adding package 'Cake.0.36.0' to folder '/home/vsts/work/1/s/build/tools'
Added package 'Cake.0.36.0' to folder '/home/vsts/work/1/s/build/tools'
Error: The assembly name is invalid.

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Bash Script
```

I think the issue is related with this one [Cake on OSX fails with "error: the assembly name is invalid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836223/cake-on-osx-fails-with-error-the-assembly-name-is-invalid)

So basically now the agent has Mono 6.8.0 and it runs into this problem. Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue was fixed after the bash task was updated to version  `3.163.1`. Now it downloads Cake `0.37.0` and the pipeline runs without problems.